# Analysis - L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: real-analysis

Here's a question I'm stuck on:

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f''(a)$ exists. Prove that

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a + h) − 2f(a) + f(a − h)}{h^2} = f''(a)$$

Suppose further that $f''(x)$ exists for all $x$, and that $f'''(0)$ exists. Prove that

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{4\left(f(h) − f(−h) − 2\left(f\left(\frac h2\right) − f\left(−\frac h2\right)\right)\right)}{h^3} = f'''(0)$$

[Warning: You may only use L’Hopital’s Rule when the appropriate conditions hold.]

I've done the first part using the first principles definition but I'm not sure how to get the second part. I guess it involves letting $x = 0$ and $h = h/2$ at some point. Since there's no term of $f(0)$ in the required expression, I think you have to cancel the terms of $f(x)$ but I can't spot an obvious way of doing so. I also can't see how L'Hopital's rule is helpful. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: I'm new to this website so if someone could edit my question to have actual fractions and limits in it, that would be great :)

Comment: I've changed the MathJax. You actually had all the right text just needs to be wrapped in $$

Comment: Observe that when you sub h = 0 into both the numerator and denominator you get 0/0. Note that you can directly let h  = 0 in say f(a+h) to get f(a). (Why??) Now apply L'Hopitals rule by differentiating both the numerator n denomimator w.r.t h.

Comment: Can you show us your "first principles" argument for the first one? I think the easiest way to proceed is to use L'Hospital once (heeding the Warning!) and then use the definition of $f''(a)$ twice, once on each half. As only $f''(a)$ is guaranteed to exist, and not any other $f''(x)$ you can't just use L'H twice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate approach for the second question that may be of interest: For simplicity, let $a=f(0), b = f'(0), c = f''(0)/2, d = f'''(0)/6.$ Then Taylor implies

$$f(h) = a + bh + ch^2 + dh^3 + o(h^3)$$

as $h\to 0.$ Use this in the given expression and the result falls right out.